# I can't solve this limit...

Tags: limits

[image: Limit]

I tried to solve it as difference of two squares. But I guess I can't move any longer from that. Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rationalize the numerator to get $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}}{\sqrt{ x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}} + \sqrt{x}}$$ You can eliminate the indeterminacy by multiplying top and bottom by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Ahaha, I wish I didn't ask this :)

Answer (score 2):

Factorizing by $\sqrt{x}$, this quantity becomes
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x}\times \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}}{x}}-1\right) &\sim \sqrt{x}\times \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}}{x}\\
& \sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}{x}}
\end{align}
So the limit is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.